# How do I add a dynamically positioned image using PDFBox

Tags: java, image, pdfbox

I am trying to create a pdf using PDFBox, add text which is dynamic, and place an image in the page in a position relative to a specific text, in this case "name1".
All of the references that I have seen are only for placing the image in an absolute position.
Is there any way to place the image dynamically?
If not, is there a way to determine the position of the line cursor at some point in the code, so that I can use that as a reference for absolute placement of the image?

```
    ...
    contentStream.showText(name1);
    contentStream.newLine();
    contentStream.newLine();
    contentStream.newLine();
    contentStream.newLine();
    
    contentStream.showText(name2);
    contentStream.newLine();
    contentStream.newLine();
    
    
    contentStream.endText();
    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("C:/pdfbox/image1.jpg", doc); 

    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 288f, 148f );
```

Comment: The PDFBox text drawing API is very lowlevel: Its methods essentially correspond to PDF content stream instructions, and when you call one of those methods, the corresponding instruction is written to the PDF content stream. To know where a given text is shown, you need to keep track of where you started and what all the instructions since did to the position the next text is drawn. Alternatively you can first draw all the text and then parse the resulting content stream with a customized text stripper. Keeping track from the start is the better option, though.

Comment: There also are third party libraries which you can use on top of PDFBox that keep track of such details for you, see https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#can-i-use-pdfbox-to-create-complex-layouts%3F